# Pass Jquery Array to phpself

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, post

Ok guys. Im new to jquery, and I have a jquery array that I need to pass as a $_POST to the same file which is called index.php. When they click the button I need it to reload the index.php so I can get the POST. Now I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here cause this isn't working. But I'm certain that its something simple that I'm missing, or that I'm doing it all wrong and I mis-understood how this works. Any help is appreciated as I've been on this and trying to figure it out for the last 6 hours.

The index.php also contains the jquery scripts which are below, and the Post check which is

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])){
echo "ok, data was sent.<br>";

echo " Data is - " .$_POST['data'];
}
```

And the Button call

```
echo "<p><input type=\"submit\" class=\"input-button\" id=\"btn-add\" value=\"Add Squad\" /></p>";
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Get items
function getItems(exampleNr)
{
    var count = 0;
    var columns = [];
    $(exampleNr + ' ul.sortable-list').each(function(){
        count++;

    columns.push($('#squad'+count).val(), $(this).sortable('toArray').join(','));
    });

    return columns.join('|');
}

$(document).on('click','#btn-get', function() {
    $.post('index.php', {'data': getItems('#squad')}
});
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  What do you expect to get and what are you getting?

Comment: It's not producting anything on $_POST. When I do an alert(getItems(#squad)) i see the data that I want/need. I'm clearly missing something. .. What do I need to do to make the page reload and get the data? Just a simple <a href after or am I missing something else?

Comment: `$('#squad'+count).val()` looks VERY suspicious.  Add your HTML to the question.

Comment: echo "<div class=\"column left\" id=\"DIV_ID" .$i. "\" style=\"color: darkorange;\"><input id=\"squad" .$i. "\" type=\"text\" name=\"S" .$i. "\" value=\"Squad " .$i. "\" style=\"text-align: center; width:151;\"></center><ul class=\"sortable-list\"></ul></div>";

This is the input call its getting #squad from. Again. Looking at the Alert(getItem(#squad)) Is getting from the div #squad, and the var you are referring too is from the input above. I'm fairly certain the getItem funtion is working fine.

Comment: I have a feeling my issue is with the button (Which I recently added above) or the jquery on click, or the way I'm dealing with post.

Comment: I am fairly certain the problem is in line `columns.push($('#squad'+count).val(), $(this).sortable('toArray').join(','));`

Comment: Right now getItems returns data like this.. 
Squad 1|2,4,6,9|Squad 2|11,3,5,8|||||||| I haven't figured out how to make it Squad 1,2,4,6,9|Squad 2,11,3,5,8|||||| But that is a different issue. I can work with that. As long as I can pass the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't doing anything with the response of your `POST`.

If you want it to submit like a form, you will need to create a form, attach a hidden input to it with your key-value pair, then submit that form. `$.post` alone is used for AJAX.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I've tried adding a <from method="post" action="index.php?go"> and nothing is happening. I'm clearly missing something. As I've tried this before and was told thats not needed. So I came here to ask cause people here seem a little more willing to help. So frustrated right now with this.

Comment: Niet the Dark Absol put me in the right direction. After some research online and some playing around I did as he suggested. You need to create a hidden input on a form, and use the form action to call itself. Then used a mouseover div to set the values in jquery. 
Hope this helps someone else.